# Dojo setQuery() on DataGrid - all items disappear?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I've racked my brain and done tons of research and testing and can't figure out what is going on.

I have a Dojo datagrid which is declared statically with some HTML. Using the GUI, my users will add items to the DataGrid, which works as it should. However, I'd like to have a function that is called at a certain point that uses Dojo's setQuery to filter the data that shows in the DataGrid. The problem is that once I run the setQuery command, ALL of the data in the grid disappears, no matter if it matches the query or not!

Here is some sample code:

```
var layoutItems = [[
    {
        field: "id",
        name: "ID",
        width: '5px',
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        field: "color",
        name: "Color",
        width: '80px'
    }
]];

// Create an empty datastore //
var storeData = {
    identifier: 'id',
    label: 'id',
    items: []
}
var store3 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore( {data : storeData} );
```

...

```
<div id="grid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" jsId="grid5" store="store3" structure="layoutItems" queryOptions="{deep:true}" query="{}" rowsPerPage="40"></div>
```

...

```
function filterGrid() {
    dijit.byId("grid").setQuery({color:"Red"});
}
```

....

```
function addItemToGrid(formdata) {
    var jsonobj = eval("(" + dojo.toJson(formData, true) + ")");

    var myNewItem = {
        id: transactionItemID,
        color: jsonobj.color
    };
    // Insert the new item into the store:
    store3.newItem(myNewItem);
    store3.save({onComplete: savecomplete, onError: saveerror});
}
```

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT, but I can't answer my own question for another 6 hours... I will post up my answer then just in case others in the future have the same problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option that I came up with, so that the filter is not running unnecessarily every x milliseconds; this basically uses JavaScript to make a new setInterval which runs once after 500 milliseconds and then does a clearInterval so that it doesn't run again.  Looks like just calling the filterTheDataGrids() function after adding an item won't do.. we have to delay for a split second and then call it:

```
// PUT THIS IN THE <HEAD> OF THE PAGE
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Declare the global variables
    var refreshDataGrid;
    var refreshDataGridInterval = 500;    // Change this as necessary to control how long to wait before refreshing the Data Grids after an item is added or removed.
</script>
```

.

```
// PUT THIS IN THE <HEAD> OF THE PAGE
<script type="text/javascript">
    function filterTheDataGrids() {
         if (dijit.byId("grid") != undefined) {
              dijit.byId("grid").filter({color: "Red"});
         }
         clearInterval (refreshDataGrid);    // Running the filter just once should be fine; if the filter runs too quickly, then make the global refreshDataGridInterval variable larger
    }
</script>
```

.

```
// PUT THIS IN THE <HEAD> OF THE PAGE
<script type="text/javascript">
    // SETUP THE LAYOUT FOR THE DATA //
    var layoutItems = [[
    {
        field: "id",
        name: "ID",
        width: '5px',
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        field: "color",
        name: "Color",
        width: '80px'
    }
]];

// Create an empty datastore //
var storeData = {
    identifier: 'id',
    label: 'id',
    items: []
}
var store3 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore( {data : storeData} );
</script>
```

.

```
 // PUT THIS IN THE <HTML> OF THE PAGE
<div id="grid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" jsId="grid5" store="store3" structure="layoutItems" query="{ type: '*' }" clientSort="true" rowsPerPage="40"></div>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addItemToGrid(formdata) {
    // THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED BY A DIALOG BOX AND GETS FORM DATA PASSED TO IT //
    var jsonobj = eval("(" + dojo.toJson(formData, true) + ")");

    var myNewItem = {
        id: transactionItemID,
        color: jsonobj.color
    };
    // Insert the new item into the store:
    store3.newItem(myNewItem);
    store3.save({onComplete: savecomplete, onError: saveerror});

    // Create setInterval on the filterTheDataGrids function; since simple calling the function won't do; seems to call it too fast or something
    refreshDataGrid = setInterval(function() {  filterTheDataGrids();   }, refreshDataGridInterval);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by running the a grid FILTER instead of setQuery periodically in the background with the help of some jQuery *(not sure if setQuery would have worked as well, I don't really know the difference between the filter and setQuery, but filter is doing what I need it to do)*.

Here is some sample code; hope this helps someone else having problems with this:

```
// ADD JQUERY
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

.

```
// PUT THIS IN THE <HEAD> OF THE PAGE
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function filterTheDataGrid() {
            if (dijit.byId("grid") != undefined) {
                dijit.byId("grid").filter({color: "Red"});
            }
        }
    // RUN THE filterTheDataGrid FUNCTION EVERY ONE SECOND (1000 MILLISECONDS) //
    // LOWER '1000' FOR FASTER REFRESHING, MAYBE TO 500 FOR EVERY 0.5 SECOND REFRESHES //
    var refreshDataGrid = setInterval(function() {  filterTheDataGrid();    }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

.

```
// PUT THIS IN THE <HEAD> OF THE PAGE
<script type="text/javascript">
    // SETUP THE LAYOUT FOR THE DATA //
    var layoutItems = [[
    {
        field: "id",
        name: "ID",
        width: '5px',
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        field: "color",
        name: "Color",
        width: '80px'
    }
]];

// Create an empty datastore //
var storeData = {
    identifier: 'id',
    label: 'id',
    items: []
}
var store3 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore( {data : storeData} );
</script>
```

.

```
 // PUT THIS IN THE <HTML> OF THE PAGE
<div id="grid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" jsId="grid5" store="store3" structure="layoutItems" query="{ type: '*' }" clientSort="true" rowsPerPage="40"></div>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addItemToGrid(formdata) {
    // THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED BY A DIALOG BOX AND GETS FORM DATA PASSED TO IT //
    var jsonobj = eval("(" + dojo.toJson(formData, true) + ")");

    var myNewItem = {
        id: transactionItemID,
        color: jsonobj.color
    };
    // Insert the new item into the store:
    store3.newItem(myNewItem);
    store3.save({onComplete: savecomplete, onError: saveerror});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you have to add jquery on top of dojo ??? You could have achieved the same by doing dojo.ready(function(){...}) instead of $(document).ready(function{...})

Comment: @Philippe You're right; that would work fine as well; I actually added the code to an already existing $(document).ready(function{...}) in my code which was using jQuery to pull some data from a TXT file on the server and place that data in a DIV on the page every couple of minutes as well as doing some masked input on some textboxes.  ...But yes, for others looking to do this, using dojo.ready(function(){...}) works great and accomplishes the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: I actually modified my code and created an alternate answer so that the filter is not running unnecessarily every x milliseconds and instead only runs after a new item is added to the Data Grid. [CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172447/dojo-setquery-on-datagrid-all-items-disappear/8216950#8216950)